# PLA not sticking to the build plate

Tags: pla, ultimaker

I have an Anycubic Chiron printer and use Ultimaker Cura for slicing.  Recently I printed a simple clip, had no problems whatsoever.

I have since upgraded Cura to the latest version, and now the PLA will not stick to the build plate.  The printer will make 3 passes whilst printing the brim, then it all collects into a ball.  I have checked the level, all is OK,  I have increased the temperatures, with the EO now at 225 °C (was 200 °C) and the bed at 75 °C (was 60 °C)

Does anyone know how much or what was changed by Ultimaker in the latest upgrade?

Comment: I doubt this is slicer related, if so, change back to an older version and test. You could even look into the G-code both versions generate. I would look into your initial gap between nozzle and bed. Please update the question accordingly, else this question is very hard to answer.

Comment: Could this be the infamous Cura filament diameter issue? If it sliced for 2.85 mm filament, that would give extreme underextrusion that would fail to adhere to the bed.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE That has been fixed now for quite some versions.

Comment: What was the version to begin with? And do you mean the latest version?

Comment: @0scar: CHEP mentioned in a recent video on upgrading Cura that he lost his profiles.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE That used to happen at any version update for some, I even posted my experience on the Ultimaker forums, but they fixed that. Strange that it is back. Nevertheless, it is a slicing problem, when you select the correct parameters it should yield the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's because of Cura. You can try if it still works with the older version.

Otherwise, clean your print bed with isopropanol before printing to remove residues or level again.  Without pictures of the condition of the print bed or the first layer, it is difficult to help.

Comment: Agreed - Cura is a portable binary, so one may just download and run the previous version and eliminate that as a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried all the possible answers and found the older version of Cura works better with the Chiron.  The printer is 3 months old, bed is cleaned after each print.

I then tried the new Cura version again but with glue for adhesion,  that works.  It seems that it is changing the bed temperature, and using a lower default.  Have tried changing the bed temperature in the software before slicing, but found I have to manually set the temperature on the printer, I have been using the generic settings for the PLA, as the ones I have (E-DA) are not in the selection or in the market place.  TPU and PETG are printing fine.

Will have to determine the optimum set-up and create my own defaults.